# Rotate the bitmap by degree in Android

Tags: android

i'm developing a shooting game with bow and arrow.. so how to rotate the BOW..?? 
i tried with different animation classes but it didnt work...

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `Matrix` class.
Here is some code you can try:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(degrees);
Bitmap bmpBowRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpBow, 0, 0, bmpBow.getWidth(),getHeight(), matrix, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

A method for rotate the bitmap

```
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap src, float degree) 
{
        // create new matrix
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // setup rotation degree
        matrix.postRotate(degree);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do the rotation manually and go frame-by-frame animation? Simply alter the bitmap that is being drawn each frame. What kinds of animation have you tried so far? I would think this could be done with a `RotateAnimation` though?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you , rotating and scaling a bitmap image using matrix parameter.

http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html